# Mongodb Connect error: Just cant connect to the database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my code

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect("mongodb:://localhost:27017/crudwithnode", {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
    .then(() => console.log("MongoDB Connected..."))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

And this is the error I got

> ```
> MongoParseError: Invalid connection string
>     at parseConnectionString (D:\Leraning Projects\Mongodb-with-nodeJs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\uri_parser.js:547:21)
>     at connect (D:\Leraning Projects\Mongodb-with-nodeJs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\connect.js:272:3)
>     at D:\Leraning Projects\Mongodb-with-nodeJs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:215:5
>     at maybePromise (D:\Leraning Projects\Mongodb-with-nodeJs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:719:3)
>     at MongoClient.connect (D:\Leraning Projects\Mongodb-with-nodeJs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:211:10)
>     at D:\Leraning Projects\Mongodb-with-nodeJs\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:709:12
>     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
>     at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (D:\Leraning Projects\Mongodb-with-nodeJs\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:706:19)
>     at Mongoose.connect (D:\Leraning Projects\Mongodb-with-nodeJs\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:333:15)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Leraning Projects\Mongodb-with-nodeJs\index.js:3:10)
>     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
>     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
>     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
>     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
>     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47 {
>   name: 'MongoParseError',
>   [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
> }
> ```

I just tried to run the file using

> node "./index.js"

Can I have an solution?

[Screen shot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOiXt.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URL string is not a valid string.

There is a standard structure of URLs i.e.

`scheme://host:port/path?query-string#fragment-id`

So for making any valid request to some resource, you have to follow the rule. Update your code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message already states, you connection string is invalid. I suspect this is because you have two colons after the protocol part (`mongodb`) in your connection string:
`mongodb:://localhost:27017/crudwithnode` sould be rather `mongodb://localhost:27017/crudwithnode`.

Comment: stefanpartheym, It works. It was the exact error. Thank you for helping me out. ♥

Answer (score 0):

Check your connection String.You have two ':' after mongodb whereas it has to be only once.

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/myapp');
```

You can find better string structuring details at 
[Mongodb connection String Spec](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/)